# what is this casting (long*)x when x is void**

Tags: c, pointers, casting, pointer-to-pointer

So I found the following code in a program:

```
static void* InterlockedExchangePtr(void** x, void* switchval)
{
    return _InterlockedExchange((long*)(x), (long)(switchval));
}
```

(I know about atomics, only thing I don't quite get is what is this typecast `(long*)(x)`)

Answer (score 0):

This casts `x`, which is a pointer to void pointer, to a pointer to `long`.

That cast is necessary because `_InterlockedExchange` expects a `long*` as its first argument and `void**` can't be implicitly converted to that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/interlockedexchange-intrinsic-functions

Comment: Strictly speaking a `void**` is not necessarily able to hold the representation of a `long*`, unlike `void*` which is a special pointer type. Also a `void*` converted to `long` is problematic since this can cause a loss of information, in case the pointer and `long` are of different sizes. So this is fishy code at best and I think the question is why it was done in this fishy manner?

Comment: @guard3 Actually yes, you're exactly right Lundin! I can't understand why would someone cast void** to long* (And not do this typecast instead: void** to long**  or  void* to long*). Honestly I didn't even know you could do this and not get an error until now

Comment: @Coffee the purpose is to cast the pointer that’s being pointed to to an integer, since pointers are integers as far assembly is concerned. If one can do atomic operations on an integer, they can also do it with pointers. This works because, at least in 32bit windows and msvc, a `long` and a pointer are both 32bits. But that function is supposed to be used internally by the winapi and shouldn’t be used otherwise, hence why that example is bad practice.